# wrong result from (float * int) calcalution in python3

Tags: python-3.x

When I run the below code in python3

```
a = 4.1
b = 1000000
c = 0
result = (a * b) + c
print(result)
```

I got this result

```
4099999.9999999995
```

Could you please tell me how to correct this calculation?

PS. This is a known issue in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Phylogenesis I see thank you so much! Could you please suggest me how to correct the calculation?

Comment: Yes. This is a known issue in Python. And an issue with all the programming languages that support fixed length floating point numbers. And with all the hardware that supports  fixed length floating point numbers. Let's say it's a sad fact of life... Having a finite amount of space
 you can encode a finite number of numbers, while reals are uncountable. — On the other hand, an error on the 16th digit is equivalent  to an error in the order of  10 μm when you are measuring the Earth-Sun distance.  If you need more precision when you are using a computer, you can have it. But it's uncommon.

Comment: @gboffi Thank you for your comments!

Comment: _"Could you please suggest me how to correct the calculation? "_ If for you 4.1 means `41/10` then `41*1_000_000/10` does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a [known behaviour on python2](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) but [also python3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).
The documentation suggests rounding the values or using the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.